# Recursive function to build breadcrumbs from json menu object

Tags: javascript, recursion, lodash

So I've been struggling to wrap my head around this recursive function and get the right results.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let config = {
    "Main": {
        children: {
            "Dashboard": "main.dashboard",
            "Account": {
                children: {
                    "Settings": "main.account.settings"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Statistics": {
        children: {
            "Test One": "main.statistics.test.one",
            "Test Two": "main.statistics.test.two"
        }
    }
}

let processNav = (config, parent) => {
    let children;
    let results = {};

    _.forOwn(config, (value, title) => {
        var breadcrumb = parent || title;

        if (value.children) {
            children = processNav(value.children, breadcrumb);
            _.assign(results, children);
        } else {
            results[value] = [breadcrumb, title];
        }
    });

    return results;
};

let breadcrumbs = processNav(config);

console.log(breadcrumbs);

// output
{ 'main.dashboard': [ 'Main', 'Dashboard' ],
  'main.account.settings': [ 'Main', 'Settings' ],
  'main.statistics.test.two': [ 'Statistics', 'Test Two' ] }
```

The output I'm looking for is more like this...

```
// expected output
{ 'main.dashboard': [ 'Main', 'Dashboard' ],
  'main.account.settings': [ 'Main', 'Account', 'Settings' ],
  'main.statistics.test.one': [ 'Statistics', 'Test One' ],
  'main.statistics.test.two': [ 'Statistics', 'Test Two' ] }
```

Can anyone help me wrap my head around this before I go crazy?

Comment: Where's `main.statistics.test.one`?

Comment: thanks for catching that, i've update the q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach doesn't use `.lodash`, just plain JS.

```js
let config = {    "Main": {        children: {            "Dashboard": "main.dashboard",            "Account": {                children: {                    "Settings": "main.account.settings"                }            }        }    },    "Statistics": {        children: {            "Test One": "main.statistics.test.one",            "Test Two": "main.statistics.test.two"        }    }};

function loop(obj, path, breadcrumbs) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {        
    if (obj[k].children) loop(obj[k].children, [...path, k], breadcrumbs);
    else breadcrumbs[obj[k]] = [...path, k];    
  });
}

let breadcrumbs  = {};
loop(config, [], breadcrumbs);

console.log(JSON.stringify(breadcrumbs, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difficulty is skipping the `children` object. Therefore, I included an additional case in the recursive pattern.

If the current "node" has a `children` property, it "skips" it by immedeately calling the next recursion:

```
isParent(obj) ? getPaths(obj.children, path, result) : /* ... * /
```

In action:

```js
const config={Main:{children:{Dashboard:"main.dashboard",Account:{children:{Settings:"main.account.settings"}}}},Statistics:{children:{"Test One":"main.statistics.test.one","Test Two":"main.statistics.test.two"}}};

const isParent = x => x.children;
const isLeaf = x => typeof x === "string";

const getPaths = (obj, path = [], result = {}) => 
  isParent(obj)
    // The "Skip" case:
    ? getPaths(obj.children, path, result)
    : isLeaf(obj)
      // The *final* case:
      ? Object.assign(result, { [obj]: path })
      // The *recurse* case:
      : Object.keys(obj).reduce(
       (r, k) => getPaths(obj[k], path.concat(k), r),
        result);
        
console.log(getPaths(config));
```